# How to create database table and insert data in postgres DB when launched by docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a spring boot app that is correctly configured to work on localhost's Postgres. I have schema.sql and data.sql in the Spring boot resource directory. When I start up it creates the table and inserts data. But now I wish to make docker container for my app and Postgres database.       I have the following docker-compose.yml. The building and start of the container are fine. But it doesn't create any table and of course, no data inserted. So how do I create table and insert data by docker-compose?

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres
    expose:
    - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dev
         - POSTGRES_USER=masi
         - POSTGRES_DB=testdb
    restart: unless-stopped
# APP
  profile_editor:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: profile_editor
    volumes:
      - ./image:/app/image
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
```

Comment: are they any errors? do you use any profile specific info?

Comment: No, I'm not. Just confused do I connect as localhost from app container to the bd container. Still learning docker

Comment: Does the app container actually successfully connect to the database (it is _not_ `localhost`)?

Comment: If it's not localhost, what is it?

Comment: if it's not localhost, what is it?